# Export the .aspx form as it is to Excel Custom Webpart SP2010/2013

Tags: csom, jsom, development

I have to show the list of users on the page (On which the particular web part is added) that **whole page have to export as it is to the Excel** with formatting.
So is it possible with the custom code or how?

Comment: Please clarify the question a bit as I have hard time understanding what is the scenario. What you have now, what you want to export and where?

Comment: My web part shows the 10 records/items, I have to Export those with Header and Footer to Excel on click of button, like an single page report.
Hope it'll make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are displaying list of users in html table, you can use jquery datatable to convert your normal html table to datatable and use Export to Excel functionality of jquery DataTable.

Please follow below link

https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

Thanks

Comment: I have to export whole page with all the controls, I don't want to export a single table.
The exporting page may contain the 10 or more tables, So, Did the above JS is support for the more than one table/multiple tables?

Comment: No above js does not support exporting whole page....generally whole page export is done to PDF/print option....!!

Comment: I have to export whole web page to excel with all the controls as it is with data.
Eg. Text Box, Check Box, Drop Down List, Radio Buttons etc.

Comment: I don't think this is possible dynamically...what you can do alternatively is create a excel with similar controls beforehand.... upload this excel somewhere and link it to you button "Export to Excel"....